# How to get vertical padding out of compact form in SASS?

Tags: sass

I'm extending an existing SASS theme (bootswatch theme actually), and I need to extract the vertical padding out of a variable set like this:

```
$panel-heading-padding:       10px 15px !default;
```

I need something like:

```
$my-vertical-padding: vertical($panel-heading-padding);
```

I've already checked the reference docs, but it seems nothing is documented.

Is this possible (without using substring)?

Answer (score 3):

After looking for the same answer as you, I ended up writing a basic function that serves this purpose:

```
@function extract-from-compact ( $value, $side ) {
    $index: 1;

    // Top values are always at index 1. The same for when the list has only one item
    @if ( $side == top or length( $value ) == 1 ) {
        $index: 1;
    }
    // Covers "vertical horizontal" style
    @else if ( length( $value ) == 2 ) {
        @if ( $side == left or $side == right ) { $index: 2; }
        @if ( $side == bottom ) { $index: 1; }
    }
    // Covers "top horizontal bottom" style
    @else if ( length( $value ) == 3 ) {
        @if ( $side == left or $side == right ) { $index: 2; }
        @if ( $side == bottom ) { $index: 3; }
    }
    // Covers "top right bottom left" style
    @else if ( length( $value ) == 4 ) {
        @if ( $side == right ) { $index: 2; }
        @if ( $side == bottom ) { $index: 3; }
        @if ( $side == left ) { $index: 4; }
    }

    @return nth( $value, $index );
}

// Usage
body {
    padding-top: extract-from-compact( $padding-list, top );
}
```

Some of the comments above explain the logics used.
Beware that this function only works for lists that work with attributes like `margin`, `padding`, etc.